# jQuery postcode validation does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate postcode field using jQuery but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
if (postcod.val().match ('~^([1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\s[A-Z]{2})$~')){
         }else{
            postcod.addClass("needsfilled");
            postcod.val(postcoderror);
        }
```

Here is html:

```
PostCode<br /><input id="postcod" type="text" value="" name="postcod" />
```

Could you help plz

Comment: What is the desired syntax of the postal code? Here in the US, unless you used the extended, you could just check if it is numeric, between 0 and 99999 and 5 characters long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few issues...

- Regexs are *not* quoted in JavaScript, unless you need to create a `RegExp` object via its constructor. In this circumstance, you don't. I only use them if I need to concatenate an outside string. While you can pass a string to `match()` and it will be implicitly converted, it's not recommended over passing a `RegExp` literal.
- You need to use `/` as the delimiters in a regex literal. When using the `RegExp`, you don't pass any delimiters. So `~` are never correct. Perhaps you are thinking PHP.
- Whilst not necessary, some of your regex could be improved. The `{1}` quantifier is implicit, and the `[0-9]` character class can be substituted with `\d`.
- Instead of having an empty block and an `else`, just negate the condition with the bang operator (`!`).

Here is how I might use it...

```
if ( ! postcod.val().match(/^([1-9]\d{3}\s[A-Z]{2})$/)){
   ...
}
```